# Как сделать цикл по времени в JS, чтобы выводились каждые 15 минут между двумя числами времени?

Tags: javascript, циклы, дата, время, for

Столкнулся с проблемой цикла. Не могу понять как написать его правильно.

Есть два времени `11:00` и `20:30`. Нужно вывести все возможные времена с разницей в 15 минут. Результатом должно быть `11:15`, `11:30`, `11:45`, `12:00` и так далее до 20:30

У меня получилось создать функции, которые переводят строковое время в дату:

```
function getDateFromHours(time) {
        time = time.split(':');
        let now = new Date();
        return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), ...time);
}
```

А также, функцию, которая добавляет 15 минут ко времени

```
function AddMinutesToDate(date, minutes) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes * 60000);
}
```

Итого, я перевожу строковые времена в даты JS:

```
var companyX = getDateFromHours(workStart);
var companyY = getDateFromHours(workEnd);
```

И пытаюсь в цикле получить все времена между этими:

```
for (let i = companyX.getTime(); i < companyY.getTime(); i=companyX.getTime() + 15 * 60000) {
        console.log(new Date(i));
}
```

Но цикл уходит в бесконечность. Подскажите,  как получить все времена с разницей в 15 минут в цикле? Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ошибка тут

```
i=companyX.getTime() + 15 * 60000
```

должно быть

```
i +=15 * 60000
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось! А можете объяснить, почему не нужно было прописывать companyX.getTime() еще раз?

Comment: Да просто, этот участок цикла который выполняется на каждом проходе. Вы каждый раз присваиваете одно и тоже. Я изменил чтоб переменная увеличивалась

Comment: Галочка с низу под стрелками если помогло

Comment: Само собой) Система просит подождать 3 мин, прежде чем галочку ставить)